# Looking for a solid and scalable library to render undirected graph

Tags: graph, nodes

I'll need to throw in about 400 millions of nodes.

Preferable languages are java, php, .net, ruby or python.
Anything alse will do the same. :D

Any ideas?

Comment: 400 million nodes means 400 Megabyte per byte of data in each node structure - If all you have is 2 pointers in your structure (they have to be 64 bit), the memory occupied is 6.4 GB

I believe a compiled language will be needed here to handle such heavy lifting. My biased opinion is to use C++ and the boost graph library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think GraphViz might handle it:)

Comment: GraphViz may be able to handle it, but in my experience it is impractically slow once you have more than several tens of thousands of nodes.  Even if the layout engine is up to the task, the visualization tools are not -- for example, you might have it output SVG, but the SVG viewers can't really handle that many objects.  You might have it output PNG, but (IIRC) PNG has a maximum size that effectively limits the number of nodes you can show.

Comment: That is a different thing:) I would say, that scalability for large images or graphs is most of the time supported only through thumbnails or cropped images.